# Getting the URL from the ajax response using EmberJS

Tags: ajax, angular, redirect, ember.js, http-status-code-302

Can anyone help me in how to get the url, from the Ajax response in Ember.
This is to handle a specific use case in which server redirects to another url and returns data from the new url(302 redirect).

If i am able to get the url form the response, then i can check if the requested url is different from the response url and can take the action accordingly.

Note: If we use Angular (tried with Angular4), then we can get the response details including url and header from the response, if you use Http service from '@angular/http'

I am using following config for EmberJS
-ember-cli: 2.14.2
-node: 8.1.0
-os: darwin x64

Comment: what have you tried? Where and how are you fetching the data? Are you talking about `ember-data`?

Comment: I was trying to get the details using `Ember.$.ajax`? If there is any other option please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comment you specified that you fetch the record using `Ember.$.ajax`. `Ember.$` is not more than an alias for jQuery. So `Ember.$.ajax` is the same as `jQuery.ajax`. Following [jQuery.ajax documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) `success` function is called with [`jqXHR` object](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) as third argument. This is a superset of browsers native `XMLHttpRequest` object. XMLHttpRequest object provides a read-only property [`responseURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL) which is what you are looking for.

In general I would recommend to not use jQuery.ajax in modern ember application. There are two great alternatives:

- [ember-fetch](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-fetch) provides a HTML5 [fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) polyfill from [github](https://github.com/github/fetch) wrapped and bundled for ember-cli.
- [ember-ajax](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax) provides a service for making AJAX requests which provides RSVP promises.

There is also work ongoing to [migrate away from jQuery.ajax in ember-data](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4929).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 
I am able to do the logic using 'ember-fetch'.